# Create list cards dynamically angularjs dashboard

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have inside of `<div class="row"> </div>` four card element like this photo

[cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHAl4.png)

[image]

I edited the code of first element. ([source code](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-bootstrap-admin-template))

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-white bg-primary" ng-controller="cardChartCtrl1">
        <div class="card-body pb-0">
          <div class="btn-group float-right">
          </div>
          <h4 class="mb-0">9.823</h4>
          <p>Members online</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I would like to know how can I dynamically create a list of cards according a sensor list I will get from API json format.

currently each cards is independent with own controller (piety I'm new to web programming, angularjs)

I would like to have some link this:

[idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nrIU.png)

[image]

How to make the code for angularjs ? (color depend of value)

Comment: Read up on creating components. You could then use an `ng-repeat` on your collection coupled with a component that contains all the code and a template to display your information. As structured your question is far too broad for anyone to be able to help you without essentially writing all the code for you.

Comment: thx it is okay,  I will study ng-repeat directive

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

```js
angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.sensorList = [{
    hour: 12,
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    hour: 12,
    color: 'green'
  }, {
    hour: 12,
    color: '#a3a3a3'
  }, {
    hour: 5,
    color: 'purple'
  }, {
    hour: 2,
    color: '#b68585'
  }, {
    hour: 12,
    color: '#d2d2d2'
  }, {
    hour: 12,
    color: '#c77cdf'
  }, {
    hour: 3,
    color: '#b68585'
  }, {
    hour: 14,
    color: 'yellow'
  }, {
    hour: 4,
    color: 'blue'
  }, {
    hour: 7,
    color: '#aeaeae'
  }, {
    hour: 12,
    color: '#d4d6d7'
  }];
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 60%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-item" ng-repeat="sensor in sensorList" ng-style="{'background':sensor.color}">
        <div>SENSOR {{ $index + 1 }}</div>
        <div>Hours: {{ sensor.hour }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```